# Should AngularJS web services return a deep copy of a response?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, design-patterns, angular-services

I have a long-polling web service. Recent response is cached. Web service notifies subscribers whenever new data is available.

Is it a good practice to return a deep copy of a response or should the data be shared with all the subscribers? Or does it simply depend on use case?

Comment: I would say Use case, but would also love to hear thoughts from others.

Comment: I don't understand that question. Each API request, even though it's long polling, is separate request, so how do you want to send copies to multiple users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first glance, I think this looks like a case where you need to look broader on the usage.

What is this service providing. It is read-only data or is the service also responsible on managing modifications to the data? Once you answer that, it might be easier so see how you should handle it.

But the truth is, the service should own the data and no subscriber of the data should be able to tamper with the result. If the subscribers should only read from the data, this should be enforced but even if they are ment to modify the data, doing so directly on the object itself is really bad practice - especially/specifically because there are many subscribers to the same data.

In the end, I believe you need to provide each subscriber with a deep copy of the data, and if that is too ressource comsuming, consider providing the subscribers with a shallow copy and expose an interface to query the nested data - which would also return copies of the data.

Any subscribers of the data should pass the data to a method responsible for saving the data, like this `service.SaveSomeInformation(responseInformation)`.

**TL;DR
Do not share the reference of the data with the subscribers, provide each subscriber with a copy of (a subset) of the data.**

Good luck

Credible source
http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html

> Defines an application's boundary with a layer of services that
>   establishes a set of available operations and coordinates the
>   application's response in each operation.

and

> ... . It encapsulates the application's business logic, controlling
>   transactions and coor-dinating responses in the implementation of its
>   operations.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, never deep copy something until you really need to.

So start by sharing your response with everyone.

Then if a subsriber needs to modify the data, for instance to complete it in a way that wouldn't break what other subscribers do but can only better serve them, then **it is more effective to keep the reference** both in term of memory space and performances.

However if a subscriber needs to do specific formatting/editing of the data privately, you should still think about weither you really need a *deep* copy, or could you simply copy the relevant information.

For instance let's say you get

```
scope.response = bigDataObject;
```

Somewhere an observer need to edit a specific property:

```
scope.data = angular.copy( bigDataObject.some.deeper.property );
scope.data.name = 'somethingElse';
```

This way tou didn't share the private edit, but neither did you deep copy the whole data. By only dealing with the smaller subset of data you actually need, you prevent side effects, save performances and memory, and keep the code understandable maintenable.